# Display a dashed line using gmaps4rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

**Environment:**
MacOSX, RoR 3.2.6, gmaps4rails 1.5.5, Google Maps API V3

**Desire:** It would be nice to display polylines on a map using gmaps4rails that can support the symbols mechanism in a Google Map.

**Referenced Documentation:**

[Google Maps API Polylines Symbols Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#PolylineSymbols)

[Google Maps API Symbol Ref](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Symbol)

[Live example of symbols on polylines](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/06/powerful-data-visualization-with.html)

[Gmaps4Rails Documentation on Polylines](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Polylines)

**Current Status of Problem** I am currently able to use the vanilla attributes (strokeColor, strokeWeight, strokeOpacity) to draw polylines utilizing gmaps4rails. The issue comes when I am trying to add the metadata for creating the symbols on the line.

**Working code in Google Map**

From the documentation for symbols on a polyline you create an icons array, with 1-n icon elements. An example from a working sample is:

```
dashed = new google.maps.Polyline({ 
  path: [
    new google.maps.LatLng(40, -80),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-50, 80)
  ],
  geodesic: true,
  strokeOpacity: 0.0,
  strokeColor: 'yellow',
  icons: [{
    icon: {
      path: 'M 0,-2 0,2',
      strokeColor: 'red',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,          
    },
    repeat: '24px'
  }],
  map: map,
});
```

Where dashed is the polyline to be created and the icons array is defined inline via SVG in Javascript.

When inspecting the object within the Chrome inspection window and setting a breakpoint before the map is finalized, you get an object formatted like so (removed the generic accessors and object references):

```
dashed
  geodesic: true
  icons: Array[1]
    0: Object
      icon: Object
        path: "M 0,-2 0,2"
        strokeColor: "red"
        strokeOpacity: 1
      repeat: "24px"
      length: 1
  latLngs: Nf
  map: sh
  strokeColor: "yellow"
  strokeOpacity: 0
```

This works all well and good. However it is javascript created in static html and applied in the onLoad() function.

**My attempt to replicate using gmaps4rails**

I have a generic map controller that loads multiple polygons, symbols, and polylines. As stated before getting generic polylines is no problem. This is the Ruby code in the controller that I am attempting to use to generate the polyline with a basic dashed symbol.

```
# Array to push created lines into for pushing through JSON
polyline_array = []
# Array to push the icons created into for use by the gmaps4rails.base.js.coffee
icons_array = []
# SVG path representation of symbol
symbol = {:path => 'M 0,-2 0,2', :strokeColor => 'red', :strokeOpacity => 1.0}
# Create actual instance of the icon element to push to the icons array
tmpIcon = {:icon => symbol, :repeat => '24px'}
# Push to the icons array
icons_array.push(tmpIcon)

@lines.each do |line|
  tmpLine = []
  line.points.each do |point|
    # Only populate the icon and line style for the first point in the
    # polylines point array
    if point == line.points.first
      tmpPoint = {:clickable => true, :linename => line.name,
        :icons => icons_array, :strokeOpacity => 0.0, :strokeColor => 'yellow'}
    else
      tmpPoint = {}
    end
    tmpPoint.merge ! :lat => point.latitude, :lng => point.longitude
    tmpLine.push(tmpPoint)
  end
  polyline_array.push(tmpLine)
end
@polyline_json = polyline_array.to_json
```

I made a modification to the gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js.coffee script to insert the icons into the polyline creation function.

```
for element in polyline
  #if we have a coded array
  if element.coded_array?
    decoded_array = new google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(element.coded_array)
    #loop through every point in the array
    for point in decoded_array
      polyline_coordinates.push(point)

  #or we have an array of latlng
  else
    #by convention, a single polyline could be customized in the first array or it uses default values
    if element == polyline[0]
      strokeColor   = element.strokeColor   || @polylines_conf.strokeColor
      strokeOpacity = 0
      # Set explicit strokeOpacity to 0 to try and match example that works
      # Would do something sexy later
      #strokeOpacity = element.strokeOpacity || @polylines_conf.strokeOpacity
      # Comment out strokeWeight to make it match object sent in working example
      #strokeWeight  = element.strokeWeight  || @polylines_conf.strokeWeight
      clickable     = element.clickable     || @polylines_conf.clickable
      zIndex        = element.zIndex        || @polylines_conf.zIndex
      icons         = element.icons         || @polylines_conf.icons

    #add latlng if positions provided
    if element.lat? && element.lng?
      latlng = @createLatLng(element.lat, element.lng)
      polyline_coordinates.push(latlng)

# Construct the polyline
new_poly = new google.maps.Polyline
  path:         polyline_coordinates
  strokeColor:  strokeColor
  strokeOpacity: strokeOpacity
  # Comment out since it doesn't exist in the object since it was commented
  # out above
  #strokeWeight: strokeWeight
  clickable:    clickable
  zIndex:       zIndex
  icons:        icons

#save polyline
polyline.serviceObject = new_poly
new_poly.setMap(@serviceObject)
```

So that is what has been changed and how I am populating the json that drives the polyline creation.

If I inspect the "new_poly" object in Chrome by setting a breakpoint right after creation and it has been added to the map using the setMap function, this is the object that is returned (removed the generic accessors and object references).

```
new_poly
  icons: Array[1]
    0: Object
      icon: Object
        path: "M 0,-2 0,2"
        strokeColor: "red"
        strokeOpacity: 1
      repeat: "24px"
      length: 1
  latLngs: Nf
  map: xh
  strokeColor: "yellow"
  strokeOpacity: 0
```

**So all that being said**
I have no idea what is going on. It would seem that for all intents and purposes the polyline objects being added to the map are structurally the same. Is there a phase within gmaps4rails that I am missing on how I add things to the map?

**Update 1 8/21/2012**
I have converted everything to use that branch. However I am getting the same issue. I have used jsfiddle to take the output from the mergedOptions object within google/objects/polyline.coffee and display the polyline as created from within gmaps4rails. On jsfiddle, it works fine, however when creating within gmaps4rails, no luck. Here is a link to the fiddle: [working dashed line](http://jsfiddle.net/N8QUC/16/)

So to make sure it was nothing in the map, I added the following to the gmaps4rails callback.

```
var icon_array = {"icons":[{"repeat":"24px","icon":{"path":"M 0,-2 0,2","strokeOpacity":1,"strokeColor":"red", "scale": 4}}],"path":[{"$a":35,"ab":-70},{"$a":40,"ab":-80},{"$a":50,"ab":-85}],"strokeColor":"yellow"};


var route1 =
[
    new google.maps.LatLng(35,-70),
    new google.maps.LatLng(40,-80),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50, -85)
];
console.log(icon_array);

icon_array.path = route1;

var path1 = new google.maps.Polyline(icon_array);
path1.setMap(Gmaps.map.map.serviceObject);
```

It creates a solid yellow line instead of expected dashed line. The object passed into the new google.maps.Polyline mergedOptions line in polyline.coffee is what I used in the above JSON parse. I had to reset the path array due to there being no type information I assume when parsing from JSON, but objectively it should be correct as you have createLatLng function that creates a google lat/lng object within the polylines.coffee script from the polyline array.

It is really strange. I started looking at the options on the map as it is created, but it seems there wouldn't be anything there that could cause issues.

Comment: Use the `objectify_js` branch on github. With this code you could pass all metadata in: `:polylines => { :data => your_data, :options => { :raw => '{ geodesic: true, ... }'}`

Comment: @apneadiving Thanks for the information. Please see the original question for an update as there isn't enough room in this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I determined what was the difference in how gmaps4rails created a map and how the jsFiddle was creating the map, and came to the conclusion that it was the api setting for the map api include from google.

On line 8 of ./lib/gmaps4rails/view_helper.rb there is the line:

```
GOOGLE     = "//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.8"
```

If you change this line to be:

```
GOOGLE     = "//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?"
```

thus removing the base version from the API call it allows for the map to display dashed lines when using gmaps4rails.

I am not sure why an explicit version call within that maps js definition would make the dashed lines not work however I am now able to utilize the custom gem to display dashed lines, and I imagine more complex SVG symbols on lines.

Thanks apneadiving for your help. I don't imagine that I would have figured this out without having downloaded the source and started digging. I imagine that this will work for the non objectify branch as well.

I will make a post on the github project as well with the findings. Thanks again, gmaps4rails has been a huge help.